# how to replot the flot bar chart when tab is changed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am  using flot bar chart in all tabs of my bootstrap portlet so I want replot the bar chart with different new data when the tab is changed. HOW CAN I do this?
Can any one help  me...